# I have windows2003+ISA 2006 + bandwidth manager but someone have bypassed my bandwidth rule! how?

Tags: bandwidth-control

I have windows 2003 and ISA server 2006 for sharing internet in an office with 200 pcs and for shaping the bandwidth I'm using bandwidth control management (the very old version) and I have a client which I know who is he, when I shaped his bandwidth to 32kbps he still able to download with the whole bandwidth's speed but when I shape his bandwidth to 1bit he is not able to do anything thus it shows he is trying to bypass the shaping rule and he is successful.

first of I want to know what kind of software or trick does he uses?(because he is one the top manager of out organization I can't access to his computer directly)
second I want to how can I defend this kind of trick?

regards.

Answer (score 1):

It's most like a P2P application that is aggressively opening up ports rapidly. This type of approach appears be able to defeat bandwidth management which is based on examining the network connections for compliance at the per connection level. It seems the P2P approach may be opening connections faster than the bandwidth management's ability to keep up with the new connections being established.

Fair Weight Queuing (FWQ - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_fair_queuing) appears to be very effective, to include managing this type of approach.

Comment: if torrent count as a p2p I myself test the network with utorrent for the sake of bypassing bandwidth and I wasn't successful :-? though I have to change the shaper software.

Comment: Torrent does count, but there are also quite a few variants out there. Some are much more aggressive than others.